# Eletrostatic induction

Tags: electrostatics, electromagnetic-induction

I know that when we are dealing with a charge inside a, initially neutral, spherical conductor, the outside induced charge will rearrange uniformly.

But, let's say now we have two conductive planes, both connected by a wire and initially neutral, with a non-conducting charged plane between it. My question is: this phenomenon (uniformly rearrange of charges on the outside face) will repeat in this case of planes?

I know that the charges on the internal faces will be different, and we can calculate it both by using Gauss Law and equal potential of planes 1 and 2 equation. But, can we claim that the charge on the outside face of plane 1 will be equal to the charge on the outside face of plane 2?